# Why does my integral equal zero when I use complex phasors?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am trying to find the expression for energy dissipation per cycle of a damper (force = cx') using

$$\frac{dW}{dt} = fx' = c(x')^2$$

My professor has used the substitution $x = X \sin(wt)$ to derive an expression for $x'$ in terms of $t$ to get the final expression:

$$W = \pi cw(X^2)$$

I tried the same integral, instead using the complex phasor substitution $x = Xe^{iwt}$, which gave me:
$$W = c(j^2)(w^2)(X^2) \int_0^{2 \pi / w}e^{2jwt} dt$$

This integral evaluates to zero and I can't see my error, if someone could enlighten me that would be great!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your equations using LaTeX.

Comment: The square should be a modulus squared, not a square. For complex numbers, the result is diferent.

Comment: I said modulus but that is wrong, I should have said the real part. When you use phasors, remember that the corresponding velocity or position is the real part of the phasor.

Comment: @RicardoMM I ran the calculation again, this time substituting e^(ix) = cos(x) + isin(x) into the integrated function, applied the limits and took the real part and still got zero. Is my integral valid or do I need to only integrate the real part of the phasor?

Comment: Only integrate the square of the real part of the phasor. Notice that the square of the phasor has real part $\cos(2\theta)$, that is diferent from $cos^2(\theta)$. The second one is always positive (which must be for the dissipated power) while the first is not.